# What am I missing on this spyder Loan Calculator?

Tags: python

I´m learning Python at one of my college classes and I was asked to create a "Loan Calculator".... I might have an idea but I´m not sure how to fix an error that I´m getting  `TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable`

This is the announcement
The user has to enter the cost of the loan, interest rate and the number of years of the loan.
Calculate the monthly payments with the following formula:

```
M = L[i(1+i)^n]/[(1+i)^(n)-1]
Data:
M = monthly payment
L = loan amount
i = interest rate (remember that 5%, i = 0.05)
n = number of payments
```

And this is my code:

```
# Loan Calculator
# Equation: M = L[i(1+i)^n]/[(1+i)(n)-1]          

print("Loan Calculator")
L = float(input("Loan amount: "))
i = float(input("Interest rate: "))
# Remember: 5% ---> i=0.05
n = float(input("Number of payments: "))
M = (L[i*(1+i)**n]/[(1+i)**(n)-1])
# M = Monthly payment

print("Monthly payment: " + M)
```

PS: I first thought I was missing convert "M" into a string, but after I changed to

```
print("Monthly payment: " + str(M))
```

I'm still getting the same error... Please help!

Comment: Your error has nothing to with the variable `M`. Its with how you are calculating it. Specifically `L[i*(1+i)**n]`, L is not an array, but a number(float)

Comment: Just change `[` and `]` to `(` and `)` respectively and add `*` after `L`: `M = L*(i*(1+i)**n)/((1+i)**n-1)`.

Comment: Thanks for your tips.... So accoding to @acw1668 should be enough with change to:
M = (L(i*(1+i)**n)/((1+i)**(n)-1))
but now I get "TypeError: 'float' object is not callable"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed a few changes:

```
# Loan Calculator
# Equation: M = L[i(1+i)^n]/[(1+i)(n)-1]          

print("Loan Calculator")
L = float(input("Loan amount: "))
i = float(input("Interest rate: "))
# Remember: 5% ---> i=0.05
n = float(input("Number of payments: "))
M = L*(i*(1+i)**n)/((1+i)**(n)-1)
# M = Monthly payment

print("Monthly payment: " , M)
```

Using some arbitrary values:

```
Loan Calculator
Loan amount: 1000
Interest rate: 9 
Number of payments: 100 
('Monthly payment: ', 9000.0)
```

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate it

Comment: Welcome! Glad to help, if this answers your question, please consider up-voting and accepting it. Thanks!

Comment: Done! Just a little question.... what is the difference between "," and "+" in the print function?? When should I use either?

Comment: Sure, as far as I know `+` python can be used when concatenating two strings, but in this case, the two items being printed were different types, string and float. So separate the string from non-strings with `,`. We could have printed M as a string, and use `+`: `print("Monthly payment: " + str(M))` which works now because they are both strings. It would have been much better if I used formatting style: `print("Monthly payment: %d" % M)` which was standard until the new formatting which now looks like this: `print("Monthly payment: {m}".format(m=M))` (not elegant at all)

Comment: Sorry for that long-winded answer: short answer: use `+` when combining and printing strings, try not to use `,` unless it is just for simple testing and basic stuff like this. Hope that helps too!